# Conditional Group Maximum

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report in CR9 that shows all live orders. 
Each live order has several operations associated with it and each of those have a status (basically if it is null it is incomplete, if it is 9 then it is complete). 
So for example:

Order 1    -   200  - Pieces of Steel

```
   Op 1      Issue Bar         (null)
   Op 2      Cut bar             9
   Op 3      Deburr Bar        (null)
```

Basically what I want to do is put the last completed operation on the same line as the order. So in the above instance, the last completed operation is Op 2 (cut bar) because it is the latest operation number that contains a 9.

I've set it up so the order number is the group and the details are the operations.

I've looked at using Maximum() by group but I don't know how to do a maximum where a condition is true statement. The maximum just returns the latest one alphabetically anyway and I need it in relation to the op number. 
I've also tried suppressing the results but I don't know how to just report on the suppressed results.

I can't use select expert to just display operations where status = 9 because there are some jobs that don't have any completed operations and these need to appear on the report too.

Comment: What is the condition you are checking as true

Comment: will op number always be in the format of OP # ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming op number is always in the format of Op # Create this formula in detail section then use Maximum() summary on this formula in group header. You can delete this formula from detail

```
numbervar a := tonumber(split({table.op#}," ")[2]);
numbervar b;
stringvar output;
if {table.finished} = 9 and a > b then 
    (b:= a;
    output := {table.op#} & " " & {table.op_description}
    );
output
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for taking the time to respond and suggest answers. CoSpringsGuy yours pointed me in the right direction.

I simplified it by just displaying the op number & " " & description if the status of the op was 9, else "". Then I just did a maximum() on the formula.

I think I must've had brain freeze or something prior to posting :)

Thanks again.

David.